# Unmanage Switch and DHCP Offer's Functionality

Tags: switch, dhcp

Does an unmanaged switch deals with providing the DHCP offers to servers, or it needs the router to assign the IP to switch first, and switch takes it from there?

**What I want to Achieve?**

I want two machines communicate within LAN.

**Setting**

My network setting for `eth0` is (i.e. `/etc/network/interfaces`):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I do restart the eth0 while it is connected to the switch, however at the end of its DHCP discovery, it states he following:

```
No DHCPOFFERS received.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a DHCP server on your LAN. An unmanaged layer-2 switch doesn't participate in anything above layer-2.